# Magento2: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setProduct()

Tags: magento2

newbie here.

I got the following error after moving date and file options to a different container.

Error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setProduct() on boolean in /html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php:250"

```
<move element="product.info.options.date" destination="custom.date" before="-"/>
<move element="product.info.options.file" destination="custom.logo" before="-"/>
```

any ideas?

Comment: custom.date exist in your case?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad I also added this on my layout for the custom.date container
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test1" before="-"/>
        <container name="custom.date" label="" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test2"></container>
      </block> 
</referenceBlock>

Comment: <move element="product.info.options.date" destination="roduct.info.form.options" before="-"/>

flush cache as well

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Thanks @HassanAliShahzad. but still not working.